# Adding a bool for each property

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I'm building a c# class that works with two different data sources. It will load a data source and take a configuration set from a function.  Then I want to do several tasks on all properties within the object.

for example.

```
    public String StreetAddress
    {
        get { return _streetAddress; }
        set 
        {
            if (value.Length <= 64)
                _streetAddress = value;
            else
                _streetAddress = value.Substring(0, 1024).Trim();
        }
    }

    public String City
    {
        get { return _city; }
        set 
        {
            if (value.Length <= 128)
                _city = value;
            else
                _city = value.Substring(0, 128).Trim();
        }
    }

    public String State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length <= 128)
                _state = value;
            else
                _state = value.Substring(0, 128).Trim();
        }
    }
```

So that holds the data from one side.  I was hoping to be able to store and set a change flag on each property.  So if we take State for example.  If the person is moved from Texas to Illinois I want to set a bool within that property to note the change then be able to loop over all changes before saving the object to the DB.  But I don't see any way to assign another state variable within that property.  Is the best way to write another object on top of this to control it or is there another more creative way to store multiple strings within the one property?

Comment: If you want to store the list of states that an a person has moved, then why don't you store it as `public List<String> States` ?

Comment: So what you really want is to know what property has changed before saving, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like an OOP way of doing the thing, you can:

Define an interface and a class for holding your property, such as:

```
interface IPropertySlot
{
    bool IsDirty { get; }
    void ResetIsDirty();
    object UntypedValue { get; }
}


class PropertySlot<T>:IPropertySlot 
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public bool SetValue(T value)
    {
        if (!Equals(_value, Value))
        {
            Value = value;
            IsDirty = true;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool IsDirty { get; private set; }

    public void ResetIsDirty()
    {
        IsDirty = false;
    }

    public object UntypedValue
    {
        get { return Value; }
    }
}
```

Store your properties inside your class in a dictionary from `String` (for name of property) to `IPropertySlot` and get/set them through a pair of methods:

```
void SetProperty<T>(string name, T value)
{
    IPropertySlot property;
    if (!_properties.TryGetValue(name, out property))
    {
        property = new PropertySlot<T>();
        _properties[name] = property;
    }

    ((PropertySlot<T>)property) .SetValue(value);
}

T GetProperty<T>(string name)
{
    IPropertySlot property;
    if (!_properties.TryGetValue(name, out property))
    {
        property = new PropertySlot<T>();
        _properties[name] = property;
    }

    return ((PropertySlot<T>)property).Value;
}
```

Finding the changed properties later is just a matter of going over the `_properties.Values` and finding which of them are `IsDirty`.

This approach also gives you a way to add more functionality to your properties in an OO manner (such as raising PropertyChanged/PropertyChanging events, mapping it to DB fields, etc.).

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to do this! Thats awesome! Im not at a dev computer at the moment to play with this but I assume I dont have to create a variable for each property.  If I send a name in this will track the property through the generic type?

Comment: I just realized something... what if I have one type of variable is of type list?

Comment: In this case you could define a ListPropertySlot and a matching interface.  This interface should derive from IPropertySlot and from generic IList and the class will implement it by redirecting list members to an internal instance of List.  On each modifying call (Add, Remove, etc.) it will update the IsDirty flag.

Comment: _properties like this?         Dictionary<string,int> _properties = new Dictionary<string,int>();

Comment: No.  `new Dictionary<string, IPropertySlot>`.

Comment: Ok great.  But I'm still having issues on this:             PropertySlot<T> property;
            if (!_properties.TryGetValue(name, out property))

Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out PropTest.PropertySlot<T>' to 'out PropTest.IPropertySlot'

Comment: Of course, my bad - there were a couple of errors in the code. See the edited answer.

Comment: Still doesn't like the assignments... property = new PropertySlot<T>(); has a compiler error of Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'PropTest.PropertySlot<T>' to 'PropTest.IPropertySlot'. And I can't seem to type case it either...?

Comment: I'm not a good compiler... As I said (but didn't write in code) : class should implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation I'd prefer an approach external to the Dto implementation.

Implement some unit that would take two instances of a class, and determine all the differences.

Map each property to compare:

```
static PropertyManager<Dto> manager = new PropertyManager<Dto>()
    .Map(x => x.City)
    .Map(x => x.StreetAddress);
```

Use two instances to compute difference:

```
    var a = new Dto{ StreetAddress = "Foo", City = "Bar" };
    var b = new Dto{ StreetAddress = "Foo", City = "Baz" };

    var differences = manager.ComputeDifferences(a,b).ToList();

    if( differences.Any() )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instances differ");
    }

    foreach (var diff in differences)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(diff);
    }
```

This sample code prints out:

```
Instances differ
x.City
```

Here is a complete code example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/4sNeoN

Comment: This is definitely a way to do it but im going to accept the below answer because its going to lead to less work.